# Jenkins build watch for new branches and build named branch

Tags: configuration, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'd like to configure a single Jenkins build ("job") which will both:

1. watch for new branches and build them when they appear
2. build a named branch or commit on request

I can achieve (1) by setting "Branches to build" to "**"

I can achieve (2) by making the build parameterised and setting "Branches to build" to "$branch" (like [this tutorial](http://julianhigman.com/blog/2012/02/22/building-github-branches-with-jenkins/comment-page-1/))

Is there any way to do both at once?

#### Motivation

My use case for (1) is that I want "feature branches" to be tested prior to merging into master, so we can see at code review / pull request time whether the changes pass all tests.

My use case for (2) is that sometimes a build fails for a spurious reason (like a flaky test) and I want to re-run it, or perhaps an old branch has fallen off the bottom of the history and I want to re-run its tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a parameterised build with no default value and also set your job to poll your source control under `Build Triggers > Poll SCM` then it should all work.

It is important that your `branch` parameter has no default value so that `$branch` is empty when the job is triggered from polling, because `Branches to build` interprets an empty value as meaning any branch.

(Note that this will build every commit, not just "new branches" as per (1), but so would any solution that sets `Branches to build` to `**` as you suggest.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach hits https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29896 in the current version of Jenkins. Hopefully that will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same shoes, enabling 'Force polling using workspace' would fix issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29896